# Through LDAP unable to read members of the domain admin group from Windows Server 2012

Tags: vbscript, server, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2

Trying to read domain admin group members through VBScript, but unable to read. Throwing error on user server.

> object not a collection

But it's working in my local test Windows Server 2012.

User Running it from member server. User is having domain admin rights.

How to check LDAP issue in server or is their anything else?

```
Option Explicit

'Get all member of a group INCLUDING members from ALL NESTED groups.
'Simply call the script with the samAccountName of the group.
'If the group name contains spaces it should be ENCLOSED IN QUOTES,
'IE scriptName.vbs "DOMAIN ADMINS"

Dim objGroup

'verify a group name was passed
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 1 Then
  WScript.Echo "NO GROUP PASSED"
  WScript.Echo "Usage:  scriptName <groupSamAccountName>"
  WScript.Quit
End If

'bind to the gorup
Set objGroup = getGroup(WScript.Arguments(0))

'enumerate the groups members
enumMembers objGroup, ""

Function getGroup(strGroupName)
  Dim objConn, objRecSet, strQueryString, objRootDSE, strQueryFrom
  Const adsOpenStatic = 3

  Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
  strQueryFrom = "LDAP://" & objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

  Set objConn = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
  objConn.Open

  strQueryString = "SELECT AdsPath FROM '" & strQueryFrom & "' " & _
                   "WHERE samAccountName = '" & strGroupName & "'"

  Set objRecSet = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  objRecSet.Open strQueryString, objConn, adsOpenStatic

  If objRecSet.RecordCount = 1 Then
    Set getGroup = GetObject(objRecSet("AdsPath"))
  Else
    WScript.Echo UCase(strGroupName) & " was not found in the domain.(" & objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ")"
    WScript.Quit
  End If
End Function

Sub enumMembers(ByRef objGroup, strInheritedFrom)
  Dim objMember

  For Each objMember In objGroup.Members '<---throwing error by saying "object not a collection"
    If LCase(objMember.class) = "group" Then
      WScript.Echo objMember.SamAccountName
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: With all the syntax errors it's not possible that this code has ever run successfully anywhere. Please post your actual code (or rather a [mcve] of it) and format it properly.

Comment: ok.thanks for suggestion.I arranged it properly now.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Probably unrelated: you have a syntax error in the line `WScript.Echo UCase(strGroupName) & ...`. VBScript doesn't support multiline strings, even if you put an underscore at the end of a line.

Comment: ok.that line i merged in to one line.

Actualy its throwing error in this function

Sub enumMembers(byRef objGroup, strInheritedFrom)

  Dim objMember

  For Each objMember In objGroup.Members<----"here its throwing 

error i feel i need add 'On Error Resume Next' in this function handle 

exception"

Comment: i marked above in code you can see in enumMembers(byRef objGroup, strInheritedFrom)  at that line its throwing error

Comment: Check the return value of your function `getGroup()`: `WScript.Echo TypeName(objGroup)`

Comment: And please avoid destroying the formatting again after someone went to the trouble of fixing it for you.

Comment: ok sorry for that i made that code easier to understand.sure.i will check .thanks for help.

Comment: i got this result after adding above suggested additional info:
adspath=LDAP://CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=net
from.
 function getGroup():objGroupObject
No,object doesnot contain value.
i guess it means it contains nothing.
but it had nested groups in it.
Domain Admins
>>>>>Denied RODC Password Replication Group
>>>>>Administrators